# How to change CPack package file name based on configuration?

Tags: cmake, cpack

In CMake, using CPack I want `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` to include `-debug` suffix in case the package is produced from Debug configuration. For single-configuration CMake generators this is probably doable by checking `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, but this does not work for multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it through the `add_custom_target` + `expression generator` + `standalone cmake script for the cpack`:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
...

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0.0")
set(CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL 1)
set(CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake")

include(CPack)

set(CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CPackConfig.cmake.in")
set(CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CPackProperties.cmake")

# make cpack configuration template for later replacements with the expression generator support
file(WRITE "${CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE}" "")
file(APPEND "${CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE}" "set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME \"\${CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME}\")\n")

add_custom_target(bundle
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    # this one must be written as is, DO NOT put the `$<CONFIGURATION>` inside a variable!
    -D "CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-win32-$<CONFIGURATION>"
    -D "CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE=${CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE}"
    -D "CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE=${CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE}"
    # this one must be after all `-D`s
    -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CPackMakeConfig.cmake"
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND}" 
    "-G" "NSIS"
    "-C" "$<CONFIGURATION>"
    "--config" "${CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE}")
```

**CPackMakeConfig.cmake**

```
if (NOT CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "* CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE variable must be defined!")
endif()
if (NOT CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "* CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE variable must be defined!")
endif()

CONFIGURE_FILE("${CPACK_BUNDLE_TEMPLATE_CONFIG_FILE}" "${CPACK_BUNDLE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE}")
```

Because the `cpack` automatically includes the `CPackProperties.cmake` script at the end of the configuration script `BundleConfig.cmake`, then you only need is just to write the real values in it at the cmake build stage (`BUNDLE` target) before the `cpack` execution.

```
cmake --build . --config Debug --target BUNDLE
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which I fixed using file(GENERATE). It's a somewhat shorter solution than the previous one :

```
set(BUILD_TYPE <IF:$<OR:$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>,$<CONFIG:Debug>>,debug,release>)
set(CPACK_PROPERTIES_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/YOURPACKAGECPackProperties.cmake")
file(GENERATE OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/YOURPACKAGECPackProperties.cmake" #allows use of generator expression to retrieve CONFIG
        CONTENT "set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME \"yourpackagename_${BUILD_TYPE}\")\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the others have made a mistake. `include(CPack)` should be placed at the end. For example:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "app")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "app-V${APP_VERSION}-${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}")

...

include(CPack)
```